# Download files from Azure virtual machine? via Remote desktop does not seem possible

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, azure-virtual-machine

How can I make a backup  of a virtual machine (<100gb), that is running Windows 2012, hosted in Windows Azure? I have a Remote Desktop access to it. I would like to make this backup to my external HDD.

Uploading all to files to somewhere and downloading them from there would take a week, so I would prefer to find an alternative way.

//// what I did.

1) copied them to desktop of a PC. Was not possible to copy to macOS. 
2) hosted some of the files using IIS and downloaded using a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vhd for the VM is a blob in Azure storage - you can simply download the VHD from Azure storage.  For example if the files are on the OS disk you can use:

```
(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname).StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.Uri
```

To get the uri and then use Get-AzureStorageBlobContent to download it.  The bottleneck will be your internet connection.